# Catching a RuntimeException 'cross-borders" in command line -- originated at one jar and thrown in another

Tags: java, jvm, classpath, runtime.exec

I'm explicitly invoking JVM from within the system i'm developing, say `systemA`. this is by specs-- I have to process the command in another jre instance.

the command to do this is

```
java -cp thisJar.jar;thatJar.jar -Djava.security.manager=mySM -Djava.security.policy=my.policy TheClass
```

, and i'm running this command by the use of `Process` and `ProcessBuilder`:

```
    StringBuilder sbResult = new StringBuilder();
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);  
    Process p=null; 
    try { 
        p  = builder.start();
        p.waitFor();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
                sbResult.append(line+System.getProperty("line.separator"));  
        } catch (Throwable t) { commandResult.error.add(t); }
        commandResult.text = sbResult.toString();
    } catch (Throwable e1) { commandResult.error.add(e1); }
```

The type `CommandResult` is plain enough:

```
public static class CommandResult {
    public String text=""; 
    public List<Throwable> error = new LinkedList<>(); 
    public int statusCode; 
}
```

Whenever there's an error "of interest" in `systemA`, i'm catching and printing it out with `e.printStackTrace()`. with this, i'm expecting it to be captured by the above code. 
However, ti isn't. the error is thrown and echoed on command prompt. however, the `BufferedReader` in the above code isn't seeing it. I'm guessing this is because the **error is happening/originating in one jar and is thrown in a class in the other jar(?)**.

Is there a way to still capture this error programmatically?

the only way i can think of is have the class throwing the error write it to a file so that the class in the other jar can read it. or hand in the error text to the class in the other jar by invoking a method of it. but there must be a better solution.

TIA.

//--------------------------

**UPDATE**

following AR.3's useful suggestion, tried the following:

```
StringBuilder sbResult = new StringBuilder();
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process p=null; 
try { 
    p  = builder.start();
    p.waitFor();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
            sbResult.append(line+System.getProperty("line.separator"));  
    } catch (Throwable t) { commandResult.error.add(t); }
    commandResult.text = sbResult.toString();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()))) {
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
            sbResult.append(line+System.getProperty("line.separator"));  
    } catch (Throwable t) { commandResult.error.add(t); }
    commandResult.text += sbResult.toString();

} catch (Throwable e1) { commandResult.error.add(e1); }
```

and

```
StringBuilder sbResult = new StringBuilder();
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process p=null; 
try { 
    p  = builder.start();
    p.waitFor();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()))) {
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
            sbResult.append(line+System.getProperty("line.separator"));  
    } catch (Throwable t) { commandResult.error.add(t); }
    commandResult.text = sbResult.toString();
} catch (Throwable e1) { commandResult.error.add(e1); }
```

still not seeing that exception. no change from before.

Comment: With your update, the exception stack trace should be stored in `commandResult.text` string field. The `commandResult.error` will _not_ catch any exception from the subprocess. That's just not how it works with two separate Java processes.

Comment: i'm looking them up both-- .text and .error. that error is nowhere.

Comment: in principle you could use the debugging interface to set exception breakpoints, but that is not something you would want to do in production. instead you should implement some form of explict communication channel between the applications

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of an exception thrown "cross-borders" between Java applications. The forking process and the subprocess are completely independent processes running in different JVMs. Normally an exception would be printed on the *error stream* of the subprocess. In order to detect such an exception or any error printed on the error stream, you'd need to read that stream, in a way similar to what you did with the output stream.

However, in this case you should remove the statement `builder.redirectErrorStream(true);` since this statement will redirect the error stream to the output stream, making it difficult to distinguish between the two types of output. In order to catch error output, just read the `Process#getErrorStream`:

```
sbResult = new StringBuilder();
// this read the error stream of the subprocess
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()))) {
    String line = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sbResult.append(line+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    // errorString would contain the error generated by the subprocess, including thrown exceptions
    commandResult.errorString = sbResult.toString();
}
```

Comment: Can you post the updated code? And did you remove `builder.redirectErrorStream(true)`? It would help you more if you make your question more reproducible.

Comment: let me look some more. tehres a ot of go-between in this prj-- hard to reproduce

Comment: pls see the update. it's because of that "cross-border' thing. but probably due to 2 JVMs-- not 2 jars. gave me some other mishaps elsewhere before and I got around them.